# What is the second argument of the "ActorRef.tell" method?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I started to learn Akka and downloaded example from [official guid](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-java/?_ga=2.260786701.144180345.1522764428-1341324091.1522667863?_ga=2.260786701.144180345.1522764428-1341324091.1522667863):

I didn't understand `tell` method second argument usage:

In main method written:

```
howdyGreeter.tell(new WhoToGreet("Akka"), ActorRef.noSender());
```

Thus second argument is `ActorRef.noSender()`

on actor side entry point looks like this:

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
  return receiveBuilder()
      .match(WhoToGreet.class, wtg -> {
        this.greeting = message + ", " + wtg.who;
      })
      .match(Greet.class, x -> {
        //#greeter-send-message
        printerActor.tell(new Greeting(greeting), getSelf());
        //#greeter-send-message
      })
```

Thus I can't have access to passed reference.

Additionally you can see that this actor send message to another actor in case of message type is `Greet.class`

```
printerActor.tell(new Greeting(greeting), getSelf());
```

Here second argument is `getSelf()` but I tried to change it with `ActorRef.noSender()` and behaviour was not changed.

printer actor entry point looks like this:

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
  return receiveBuilder()
      .match(Greeting.class, greeting -> {
          log.info(greeting.message);
      })
      .build();
}
```

Thus it just prints provided message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> printerActor.tell(new Greeting(greeting), getSelf());
> ```
>
> Here second argument is `getSelf()` but I tried to change it with `ActorRef.noSender()` and behaviour was not changed.

The second argument to the [`tell()`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/actor/ActorRef.html#tell-java.lang.Object-akka.actor.ActorRef-) method is the sender reference to which the recipient actor can send a reply. In other words, if actor A sends a message to actor B with `getSelf()` as the second argument to a `tell()` call, then actor B can use `getSender()` to obtain a reference to actor A. Passing `ActorRef.noSender()` as the second argument is appropriate when the recipient actor doesn't need a reference to the sender. Note that you can use any `ActorRef` as the second argument to `tell()`.

The printer actor in the quickstart guide doesn't call `getSender()` when it receives a `Greeting` message. The only thing that the printer actor does when it receives a `Greeting` message is log the greeting. That being the case, it would make more sense for the greeter actor to use `ActorRef.noSender()` instead of `getSelf()` (but, again, in this case it makes no difference because the printer actor doesn't call `getSender()`):

```
printerActor.tell(new Greeting(greeting), ActorRef.noSender());
```

If you want to see how the sender reference could be used, you could change the printer actor's behavior:

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
  return receiveBuilder()
    .match(Greeting.class, greeting -> {
      log.info(greeting.message);
      getSender().tell(new PrinterAck(), ActorRef.noSender());
  })
  .build();
}
```

Then change the greeter actor to handle a `PrinterAck` message (obviously you would need to define a `PrinterAck` class):

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
  return receiveBuilder()
    .match(WhoToGreet.class, wtg -> {
      this.greeting = message + ", " + wtg.who;
    })
    .match(Greet.class, x -> {
      printerActor.tell(new Greeting(greeting), getSelf());
    })
    .match(PrinterAck.class, x -> {
      log.info("Received an ack from the printer actor.");
    })
    .build();
}
```